# How accurate is the Pencak Silat in The Raid: Redemption?

Tags: pencak-silat, entertainment

The Gareth Evans-directed movie [The Raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Raid_(2011_film)#Accolades), alternatively titled The Raid: Redemption in the US, is about a young Indonesian cop who fights his way out of a criminal complex, relying strongly on his practice of Pencak Silat.

How accurate is the practice of Penkat Silat shown in the movie? How much liberties were taken with it, if any?

Comment: As far as I know, both Iko Uwais and Yayan Ruhian are real Silat practitioners. So I guess most of their stunt actions are based on Silat (to a greater extent)